# if/else statement fail

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I'm using `if/else` statements as below, but the script fails in Selenium WebDriver. Here, for one test case the `if` statement works but, for another test case, the `else` one doesn't.

```
if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Tooltip__body.Tooltip__body--top")).isDisplayed()){
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Tooltip__body.Tooltip__body--top")).click();
    }
    else
    {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Tooltip__body.Tooltip__body--bottom")).click();
    }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: hi nicomp, the test case fail's.

Comment: As test case failed, you assert no other element than the desired were received the click? Or what error test case returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not good at Java, so im putting the steps. Give try.
   1. First Find elements seperately. 
 2. Now check if 'top' is not null and then check for is displayed and can continue further .Pseudo code below

```
IWebElement top= driver.findelement( put you locator top here )
 IWebElement bottom = driver.findelement( put you bottom here)
 if(top!=null)
 {
  if(top.IsDisplayed)
  {
   top.click()
  }
}
else
{
  if(bottom!=null)
  {
    bottom.click()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        try
        {
        if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Tooltip__body.Tooltip__body--top")).isDisplayed()==true)
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Tooltip__body.Tooltip__body--top")).click();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Tooltip__body.Tooltip__body--bottom")).click();
        }
```

Comment: Hi Leon, I can see error at catch(). says parameter expected. Could you help on this please to try again.

Comment: its already better, try to look if you write correct cssSelector.

Comment: I have checked again leon, cssSelector is right, but on the code given by you i can see error on catch() line, which says parameter expected.

Comment: what kind of exception not visible / not clickable ?  (can you write the element tag ?)

Comment: Could you click on the link for the issue mentioned please
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Z2aZLgKc7wT2VNUzIxNldtUHc

Comment: I see please type catch(Exception ex) after that you will see what the reason of it

Answer (score 1):

we need to click on element "div.Tooltip__body.Tooltip__body--top" if it is displayed. if not then need to click on "div.Tooltip__body.Tooltip__body--bottom"

If we use .isDisplayed to check element displayed or not, in any case element is not there, it will throw exception. that's why we need to handle this exception by using try/catch.

```
    try{

        //if element is displayed, then click it
         if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Tooltip__body.Tooltip__body--top")).isDisplayed()==true){
             driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Tooltip__body.Tooltip__body--top")).click();
    }

    }catch(Exception e){

        //exception occurred as element (top) is not available.
        //so i need to click on bottom
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Tooltip__body.Tooltip__body--bottom")).click();
         //if required we can collect exception : e.getMessage()

    }
```

Thanks